# Почему отступ считается по разному на разных девайсах?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Мне нужно поднять активити вверх на 15% от высоты экрана(вне зависимости от того какой экран, элемент должен подняться на 15%) за пределы видимости экрана... Я делаю это таким образом

Вот у меня есть кастомная вьюха

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


/.../


<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView>


/.../


</RelativeLayout>
```

**вот здесь я устанавливаю параметры, чтоб это сделать**

```
private void initVar() {
//  Margin set in % of the screen
    int marginLeft = 0;

------>   int marginTop = 15; вот здесь я указываю процент от высоты экрана

    int marginRight = 0;
    int marginBottom = 0;

//      Здесь мы получаем высоту и ширину экрана
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

//      Здесь мы устанавливаем параметры для нашего вью
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    param.setMargins((screenHeight * marginLeft) / 100, -((screenHeight * marginTop) / 100),
            (screenHeight * marginRight) / 100, (screenHeight * marginBottom) / 100);

    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

и вот что получается, когда я загружаю это все дело на телефон Samsung S5 1980x1080 то это выглядит как я и рассчитываю, ровно 15% занято(белая полоса снизу это дефолтный цвет экрана который открывается когда мы поднимаем вью)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Но когда я тот же проект загружаю на эмулятор 1280x800 то почему то экран поднимается не на 15% а на 25-30%(точно не на 15%)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А если попробовать на эмуляторе с разрешением 1440*2560, то получается вот так**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первом скриншоте белая полоса  не доходит до надписи "Front picture", а на втором захватывает его и даже больше а на а на третьем это вообще 50% экрана...

Очень странно получается потому что формула по которой идет расчет подразумевает, что я беру высоту экрана и получаю от нее ровно 15%...

**Почему на одном устройстве это 15%, а на другом  это больше а на третьем это вообще 50% экрана??**

**Что я делаю не так??**

**Вот скриншот на котором `margin` установлены на 0 и на экране не должно быть белой полосы, но она есть, хотя на реальном девайсе ее нет...**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть такой класс `PercentRelativeLayout` и библиотека поддержки [support:percent](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en) - он позволяет задать размеры напрямую в процентах, возможно он вам поможет.

Comment: @pavlofff мне кажется причина в том, что для вывода картинки с камеры на экран я использую `AutoFitTextureView` который автоматически подбирает наилучшие размеры и соотношение сторон для себя и когда размеры динамиски посчитаны то в него устанавливается превью (картинка) с камеры... И вот я думаю, что вся проблема в том, что `AutoFitTextureView` при разрешении экрана 2550 * 1280 оно просто не может равномерно растянуться на всю площать сохраняя правильное соотношение сторон... Как вы считаете? Может это быть правильным? Не знаю как это проверить правда...

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно учитывать плотность экрана. Данные (ширина и высота) дисплея из системы вам выдают в пиксилях и они реальны. Но когда вы указываете в коде `дополнительные` цифры, их нужно пересчитывать под плотность экрана.
К примеру, вы хотите добавить `15` пикселей высоты для вьюшки. Вы берете  `view.getHeight()` и получаете размер в пикселях и когда прибавите просто число `view.getHeight() + 15`, на экранах с разной плотностью эффект быдет выглядеть по разному, где нормально, где меньше. Но выполнив `view.getHeight() + dpToPx(getActivity(), 15)`. Ваши `15` пикселей пересчитаются в реальные пиксели для вашего экрана.

```
 public static int dpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
        // add 0.5 to round up
        return (int) ((dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5);
    }


    public static int pxToDp(Context context, int px) {
        // add 0.5 to round up
        return (int) ((px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5);
    }
```

**UPD**
Технически у вас расчеты правильны. За исключением того, что вы берете расчет высоту всего экрана. У вас не учитывается высота софтварных кнопок (бек\хом\таск) берите высоту вашего контейнера, а не высоту экрана. Так как высота контейнера известна только после ее создания, вешайте лайоут обсервер (к примеру в onCreate).

```
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mViewRoot.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int viewHeight = mViewRoot.getHeight();
                mViewRoot.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                      // тут все ваши расчеты
                 }
            });
```

`mViewRoot` - это Ваш рутовый контейнер. И все равно при расчетах в % у вас будут отличаться цифры, а значит оно не будет выглядеть одинаково на всех устройствах(я правильно понимаю? что кнопка фото у вас статичного размера :)). Я бы рекомендовал выставить в xml нужную высоту в для нижней view (`mTextureView`) , и изменять в пропорциях размер превью камеры (на остаток высоты) ;)

Comment: прошу прощения мои мысли пока писал перепутались, я обновил свой ответ

Comment: Ок, но я а своем примере вроде ничего ни к чему не прибавляю... Я просто получаю высоту(допустим 100) и узнаю сколько от этого числа будет 15%, в итоге получаю число 15 и устанавливаю его в `setMargins()`... или вы имеете ввиду как раз в этот момент когда я устанавливаю `setMargins()` нужно конвертировать? Получается получил я 15% от 100 = 15, сконвертировал в пиксели и установил в `setMargins()`? Верно?

Comment: Все равно не получается, ваш способ возвращает слишком большое значение... Получается так `screenHeight is : 1920`, потом то, что возвращает мой способ `calculate is : -288` - и это действительно 15 % и вот так возвращает ваш метод `dpToPx is : -863` это точно не 15%...

Comment: Надеюсь обновление в ответе будет более полезным ;)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так высоту/ширину экрана получать:

```
public static int getWidth(AppCompatActivity act)
{
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    return displaymetrics.widthPixels;
}

public static int getHeight(AppCompatActivity act)
{
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
}
```

Comment: Одно и тоже получается... Вот более интересен вопрос, как так получается когда я проверяю высоту на реальном устройстве которая равна 1920, то мне и ваш способ возвращает 1920 и мой способ возвращает 1920, но когда я тоже самое делаю на эмулаторе, допустим на устройстве с высотой 2560, то мне почему то возвращается в любом случае 2392... 168 он не досчитывает... Когда я проверил на эмуляторе с высотой 1280 мне вернулось 1184... опять не досчитал 96... при чем в первом случае это 6,5% недосчета, а во втором 7,5... Не пойму какая зависимость...

Comment: И еще Юрий, вопрос не по теме, как вы сделали картинки меньше? Я не нашел этой функции...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну, возможно проблема в эмуляторе... Вы какой пользуете? GenyMotion или стандартный студии? А на реальных девайсах везде нормально работает?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko 168px (96px - в зависимости от экрана) это высота програмных кнопок управления (домой, назад, меню) для устройств, где нет аппаратных кнопок - они не учитываются в размере, доступном приложению.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, а картинки уменьшаются добавлением буквы в конец ссылки, сразу перед расширением файла. Там несколько вариантов. В данном случае я поставил просто `m`

Comment: @pavlofff да, но почему тогда в моем случае этот отступ на одном экране есть , на другом уже нет... и почему он учитывается именно для `TexterView` на которое выводиться картинка с камеры, но там где у меня кнопки оно уже не учитывается и кнопка нарисована прям на нем... Можно ли как то это отключить? И вот я приложил скриншот в описание к вопросу в котором значение всех `margin`ов установил на 0 и на экране не должно быть вообще белой полосы...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо! Я не знал...

Answer (score 0):

На вашем месте, я бы наверно начал действовать так же. Но сейчас уже есть готовое [решение из коробки appcompat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).
Это `PercentRelativeLayout` который позволяет задавать размеры дочерних вью в процентах.

Comment: Да, но если я таким способом задам фиксированые размеры то мое изображение получиться растянутым в ту или иную сторону в зависимости от экрана... Или я не так, что то понимаю?

Comment: не будет, если правильно задать scaleType

Comment: Я так понимаю, что в нашем случае нужно задать `fitStart` , чтоб картинка заняла место в правильный пропорциях...  Но как ни крути картинка займет не весь экран и все равно останется не занятое место, если сделать, чтоб картинка занимала весь экран это будет означать, что ее нужно подтянуть к какому нибудь краю и она растянется... Вроде так...